# Not able to get buffering state of live video using mpmovieplayercontroller ios

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am working on playing live streaming video using MPmovieplayercontroller. I can also display time of video playing. I am able to play video but when it gets buffer and regain its playing state meanwhile not able to get buffering state and so timer is not getting updated properly rather it jumps with some time.Is there any way to get it proper? Please help me to resolve. Thanks in advance

My code is here:-

```
   NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "moviePlayBackStateChanged:", name: "MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification",object:  moviePlayer)
    if(moviePlayer?.playableDuration > 0)
                        {
                            currentTime = moviePlayer!.currentPlaybackTime
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            currentTime = 0
                        }
    func moviePlayBackStateChanged(notification:NSNotification)
        {
            if(moviePlayer?.loadState == MPMovieLoadState.Playable)
            {
                currentTime = moviePlayer!.currentPlaybackTime
                println("currentTime\(currentTime)")
                lblTime?.text = stringFromTimeInterval(currentTime!)          
            }else if(moviePlayer?.loadState == MPMovieLoadState.Stalled)
            {
                lblTime?.text = stringFromTimeInterval(currentTime!)
            }
}
```

Comment: did you find any resolution?

Comment: @Saty Yes I have did below code:-

`override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {

  if(object as NSObject == item1! && keyPath == "playbackBufferEmpty")
  {
   if(item1!.playbackBufferEmpty)
   {
    //code
   }
  }
 else if(object as NSObject == item1! && keyPath == "playbackLikelyToKeepUp")
  {
   if(item1!.playbackLikelyToKeepUp)
   {
    //code
   }
  }
}`

Comment: This is for AVPlayer I think. Can I use this with MPMovieplayerController

Comment: @jalak...Can I use this code if I am using MPMovieplayerController?

Comment: @Saty You can try this code. It may work.

Comment: can you provide me full code like item1 is of type what

Comment: can you send me the AVplayer code as well